# Descrete Color Mapping for Node background-color using cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, color-mapping

I am new in Javascript and Cytoscape.JS, I try to use a discrete color mapping for my nodes based on a property given in my data. The property has e.g. five unique values (a, b, c, d, e). In other words, I would like to color the nodes based on the group there are belonging.

Therefore:

1. Is it possible to autogenerate color based on the number of unique value (here 5)
2. How to assign these color to all nodes

I hope this question is understandable.
Lazloo

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to generate random colors, and create an object map to store the color with different values, e.g. `{a:'#red', b:'#blue'....}`. Then set a property like `bgColor` in your node object with the color map, in the node style just set `'background-color': 'data (bgColor)'`.